# web3.js new accounts without local node!

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am trying to develop an dapp, but since I am running a small server (Windows Sever 2012 R2) with limited space I don't want to host/install an ethereum node, nor geth in my server, because as many of you know it takes many Gb of hard drive.

However, my "dapp" is a simple HTML page for registration. Essentially this page allows users to register and every time a registration occur; I need to designate/create a new ethereum public address with it corresponding private keys for the user. I am planning to save this information in my database (don't judge). Since I am not hosting a node in my server, I know that I need a third party to connect to mainnet in blockchain, therefore, I am using infura! I know some developer say that you can create wallets with: `web3.eth.accounts.create()` but the fact is that I can use this code in node.js manually and I am able to create new wallets just fine with the following code:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');     
var infura = "ws://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || infura);  
web3.eth.accounts.create(["this is my seed phrase"]);
```

but when I try to implement the same approach in HTML it doesn't work.
I also try keythereum.js to create wallets with the following code:

```
var keythereum = require("keythereum");
var dk = keythereum.create();
var readableAddress = keythereum.privateKeyToAddress(dk.privateKey);
console.log("public address:" + readableAddress);
console.log("private key in hex:" + dk.privateKey.toString('hex')
```

but not luck. I suspect that I may need other dependencies ir order to make it work. Can someone guide me please?

This is the code of my page!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>  
    <title>Test</title>                   
    <script src="js/web3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/keythereum.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<scrip> <!-- keythereum.js code -->
var keythereum = require("keythereum");
var dk = keythereum.create();
var readableAddress = keythereum.privateKeyToAddress(dk.privateKey);
console.log("public address:" + readableAddress);
console.log("private key in hex:" + dk.privateKey.toString('hex')
</script>

<script> <!-- web3.js code -->
var Web3 = require('web3');      
var infura = "ws://mainnet.infura.io/v3/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   
var web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || infura);  
web3.eth.accounts.create(["this is my seed phrase"]);   
</script>
    </head>
<body>
<h1>Registration</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Error I get:

> Error: Provided address "undefined" is invalid, the capitalization
>   checksum test failed, or its an indrect IBAN address which can't be
>   converted. web3.min.js:1:349717

Comment: The error appear to be unrelated to your code. Can you determine the exact line that generates that error?

Comment: It shows web3.min.js:1:349717

Comment: I saw that line in the first error message that is because you are using the minified versions of web3. Can you try with unminified versions? Also which line of **your code** does generate that error message? (try commenting out lines until you find it).

Comment: I have changed web3.min.js to web3.js as you recommended, I also downgrade the beta 36 version to 34 because there is not web3.js file in the last version. Now with the same code I have the following error: " ReferenceError: require is not defined "

Comment: You do not have to use require from a web page, when the web3.js is load it will create a Web3 object (same for keythereum).

Comment: If I take that variable out of the code it doesn't work. Can you point out a real example to see how they do it?

Comment: Here is an article with an example how to access web3 from an html page https://medium.com/@yangnana11/interacting-with-a-smart-contract-through-web3-js-tutorial-56a7ff2ff153

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use `web3-eth-accounts` package for account's creation

```
const Accounts = require('web3-eth-accounts');
const accounts = new Accounts();

const { address, privateKey } = accounts.create();
```

Comment: Aquila. The code that you share, can be implemented in html without node or geth?

Comment: @Mula yes, you can

Comment: I appreciate your input but you code doesn't work.

Comment: most probably you didn't add script to your page, there is CDN you can use https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/web3-eth-accounts

Answer (score 0):

Automatically the library creates a keythereum object.
Try this code:

```
var dk = keythereum.create();
var readableAddress = keythereum.privateKeyToAddress(dk.privateKey);
console.log("public address:" + readableAddress);
console.log("private key in hex:" + dk.privateKey.toString('hex'));
```